# How to solve 'returned null' when parsing a huge XML page with C

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2, clob

I'm trying to parse a huge XML clob data from oracle DB in Redhat linux 5.5, 64bit, using libxml2-2.7.6

**But when I tried to parse the XML more than 400KB(409600 bytes), the xml parser function, 'xmlParseMemory' returned null pointer.**

(Succeeded to load from XML clob data to string in C, checked the string 'sData' is filled with the data correctly.)

```
xmlDocPtr xDoc;
...
xDoc = xmlParseMemory(sData, strlen(sData));
if(xDoc == NULL)    return -1;
...
```

Parser does work when the size of XML is less than 400KB.
But only when more then 400KB, paser returns null pointer despite correct string data, 'sData'.

And I've already tried xmlReadDoc, xmlReadMemory with using xmlMemSetup before xmlInitParser.

How can I solve this situation with using xml parser functions?

Answer (score 0):

If everything works for XML with less than 400KB, I believe the problem is because of your `sData` buffer.
You should check if the buffer has enough space for large file (more than 400kb):

- How much memory you allocated for `sData`?
- Does the `strlen(sData)` valid?

Comment: Unfortunately Yes, ```sData``` has been dynamically allocated with calloc. It is allocated with the length of CLOB. And ```strlen(sData)``` is also valid showing correct the length of sData when I log it.

Comment: Appreciated!! It caused from incomplete ```sData``` allocated in memory. One of the tags was wrongly put in the memory:)

Comment: Nice to hear that you've solved the problem. Have a nice day!